# Allow access to specific folders for Guest user on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, guest-account

I have just turned on the Guest account on my Windows 7(64bit) system. This is what I require the Guest user should / shouldn't have:

1. Guest should not have access to D: drive (any other drive except C:)
2. But there are specific folders on D: drive for which I want to give him 'Read' access. Also he should only be able to see those specific folders only, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

The following procedure will assume you're using the built-in Guest account, and that its profile path is `C:\Users\Guest`.

### Preliminary steps

1. Log on with the Guest account, and then log off. This is just to ensure the profile gets initialized, in case it's not already.
2. Log on with an administrator account, and open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).

### Hide and prevent access to any drive but C: from My Computer

Type or paste the following commands in the command prompt, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> each time:

```
reg load "HKU\Guest" "%SystemDrive%\Users\Guest\NTUSER.DAT"
reg add "HKU\Guest\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoDrives" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x3fffffb /f
reg add "HKU\Guest\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v "NoViewOnDrive" /t REG_DWORD /d 0x3fffffb /f
reg unload "HKU\Guest"
```

### Deny access to drives and all their subfolders

1. Type or paste the commands below, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   takeown /f D: /a
   icacls D: /deny *S-1-5-32-546:(OI)(CI)(F)
   ```
2. Repeat step 1 for any other drive you want to restrict by replacing `D:` with the actual letter.

### Grant read and execute access to specific folders

1. Execute the following command:

   ```
   icacls "D:\SomeFolder" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-546:(OI)(CI)(RX)
   ```
2. Repeat the previous step for all other folders you want to make available to the Guest account.

### Create junction points in C: drive to access specific folders

1. Create a dedicated container by running these commands:

   ```
   md "C:\GuestDrive"
   icacls "C:\GuestDrive" /grant:r *S-1-5-32-546:(OI)(CI)(RX)
   ```
2. Create a junction point to access the actual folder:

   ```
   mklink /j "C:\GuestDrive\SomeFolder" "D:\SomeFolder"
   ```
3. Repeat step 2 for any other required folder.

### References

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [Using Group Policy Objects to hide specified drives](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289/en-us)
- [Prevent access to drives from My Computer](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2663)
- [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330/en-us)
- [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)

Comment: Worked just the way I wanted

Answer (score -1):

Why not map those folders you would like the guest to see as new drive letters and give the user access to those? You can then hide the D drive.

Comment: Can you detail a bit. Also I don't know if its a good idea to create new drives for specific folders.